# HELP PLEASE PHP slider css

Tags: php, images, css

I converted a html file to php to upload in a hosting site. However, I have this slider that already came with the template I used. The background image doesn´t show in php, but it does in html.

This is due tomorrow and I want to die.
[image]
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: lets run inspect on that grey screen in the browser and then show us what the console says

Answer (score 0):

The main problem appears to be related to the path of your image. It's likely that the path is now incorrect due to the introduction of a new directory in your updated URL called **shionhouse-master**.

To fix it, ensure that you've included the accurate file path for your background image. You can use your browser's developer tools to inspect whether the image path is correct and matches the new directory structure.

Comment: I deleted the dots in my url, and updated the path but I still can´t see the image

Comment: Just getting rid of the dots won't do the trick. Let's dig a bit deeper. Take a close look at the filepath to make sure you've got the right one. Begin by checking the URL of the background image to see if it's pointing to the correct image file. This guide can walk you through the process: https://phancybox.com.au/how-to-save-an-image-from-a-website/. It's a helpful resource!